# Change background color when selected

Tags: html, css

I want my links with border to change background color to blue when it's clicked. I want it to keep the new background color after being clicked.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<nav class="entry-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href="#" title="För elever">För elever</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus last">
                            <a href="#" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href="#" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.entry-links > ul li a,
.entry-links > ul li span
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is how they look like now:
http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/1524/

When selected, I want them to change background color to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kq3ja99r/

Comment: Selected how? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: selected as in being clicked?

Comment: @Paulie_D Being clicked

Comment: If you click it...it will go to a new page so I suspect clicking is not what is required....unless you mean clicked and held...as in `:active`

Comment: @Paulie_D I want it to keep the new background color after being clicked. :active is not what I was looking for

Comment: @John then you will have to use JS, or `:target`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this -- using the adjacent css selector :

```
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="content"></div>

btn:active + .content{
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etsvsb4o/

Use the :focus pseudo class

```
{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RASJ/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the change after being clicked, then you have to use JavaScript:
JS:

```js
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-links")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i =0; i < link.length;i++){
  link[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.add("highlight");
    }
}
```

```css
.entry-links > ul li a,
.entry-links > ul li span
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.entry-links > ul li a.highlight{
      border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 10px 40px; 
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="entry-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href="#" title="För elever">För elever</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus last">
                            <a href="#" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href="#" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: I want it to keep the new background color after being clicked. :active is not what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try By Adjusting **id** acc. to **href**-

```css
.entry-links > ul li a,
.entry-links > ul li span
{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.entry-links > ul li a:target,
.entry-links > ul li span:target {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="entry-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href='#a' id='a' title="För elever">För elever</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus last">
                            <a href="#b" id='b' title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="focus first">
                            <a href="#c" id='c' title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```